# Custom Object or Big Object for dataset of 3 million records

Tags: apex, custom-object, big-object

I am sort of confused in what approach to take in storing large amounts of data in Salesforce. I have some data that is between 2 - 3 million records and I want to access that data through apex code to create a snapshot and make it viewable to the user.

I have been reading about having it as a:

1. Custom Object - if it is as a custom object, how long would the data retrieval process take.
2. Big Object - I have heard that we cant access this data through apex.

I have also thought about creating apex batch jobs to work on the data and push the snapshot to a custom object.

Comment: What type of coding or logic are you looking to perform on the data?

Comment: The logic I am going to apply will be to create a summary of the whole data to be view-able by the end user.

Comment: Does the data already exist in Salesforce or are you planning a load strategy?

Comment: Data doesn't exist in Salesforce now, I am trying to figure out what approach to take on this before loading the data.

Comment: [apex is available on BigObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_considerations.htm) - just not triggers

Comment: @sumchans I'm concerned this question is too broad, and leading to a lot of follow-up. Could you [edit] in some of the detail from comments and focus on a question to which we can provide a concrete answer? I recommend reading the whole [Big Objects Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object.htm) and perhaps [Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_introduction.htm).

Comment: Sure @DavidReed, I have deleted 2 of my comments, just waiting on the right way to get this figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to the question but an attempt to provide the context and resources required to arrive at an answer.

You should read the following documents in their entirety:

- [Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_introduction.htm).
- [Big Objects Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object.htm)
- [Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm).

The questions you're asking here are not directly answerable because they are implementation-specific and/or require a comprehensive discovery to ascertain.

> Custom Object - if it is as a custom object, how long would the data retrieval process take.

Impossible to answer; depends on the query, the Apex complexity, the server load, and so on.

> Big Object - I have heard that we cant access this data through apex.

That is not entirely accurate. Big Objects can be [queried from Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_querying.htm) provided the query meets very specific requirements to use the Big Object's indexes.

Additionally, Big Objects can be queried asynchronously with [Async SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/async_query_overview.htm) to produce a digested or summarized data set in a custom object. It's *possible* that this could apply to your use case.

> I have also thought about creating apex batch jobs to work on the data and push the snapshot to a custom object.

If you are not using Big Objects and Async SOQL, you'd almost certainly have to do so. Note that writing batch classes that aggregate data across millions of rows can implicate some less-common governor limits (how much heap do you need to track your state?)

#### Potential Side-Step Solution

If your data set is *static* - you need it in Salesforce for some reason but it's not going to change once loaded - precalculate all of the summary data outside Salesforce and load it at the same time.

If your data set is only modified *outside Salesforce*, similarly consider using an off-platform, ETL approach to get your summary information.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed. I really the appreciate the effort that you put in here to explain  everything in detail. Now I have an idea on what approach to take in my case. I might try out the big objects first as it will also give me an opportunity to learn to deal with big data. I am not sure how to answer this "How much heap do you need to track your state?